# Integrating velocity over space graph to get time

Tags: integration, physics

Given the following graph, where the y-axis is velocity (m/s) and the x-axis is space (m):

[image]

$$v(s) = \begin{cases}
 \sqrt{5s} & s < 20 \\
 10 & s \geq  20
\end{cases}$$

The question is about how much time the body needs to move the first 100 meters.

From 20 to 100 meters it needs 8 seconds. But I'm not sure how to solve the square root part. How can it be solved by integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We have
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{5s}.$$
This is a *separable differential equation*. Rewrite as 
$$\frac{ds}{\sqrt{5s}}=dt$$
and integrate. Remember to use the initial condition to evaluate the constant of integration.